# How can I filter results by number of associated objects in Apache Solr?

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

Let's say I have Apache Solr index, with posts and comments. They are connected via post_id. How Can I query for MoreLikeThis posts with more than 1 comment?

Answer (score 2):

You've to **customize apache solr search results** or simply write a hook / function for search results which will decrease ranking of result. Some idea is presented [here](http://www.brightlemon.com/blogs/customizing-apache-solr-search-results-0) and [here](http://www.solrtutorial.com/custom-solr-functionquery.html)

Comment: Could you explain it in details? With SQL equivalent terms